# why i am getting error when sending data from one fragment to another

Tags: java, android, bundle

have read these questions and many others but no one has easy explanation

[send data from one fragment to another using bundle . i tried this. it's not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771823/send-data-from-one-fragment-to-another-using-bundle-i-tried-this-its-not-wor)
[Why can I not get my app to successfully send data from one fragment to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210199/why-can-i-not-get-my-app-to-successfully-send-data-from-one-fragment-to-another)

hi, i am very new to programming and stackoverflow

i have created a MainActivity in which i have two fragments

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="fragments.first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:name="fragments.second"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</fragment>
```

in my first fragment i want to send data to second frament when i click button

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String question = questions1.getText().toString();
        String ans1 = answer1.getText().toString();
        String ans2 = answer2.getText().toString();
        String ans3 = answer3.getText().toString();
        String ans4 = answer3.getText().toString();
        Map<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hashMap.put("Answer 1",ans1);
        hashMap.put("Answer 2",ans2);
        hashMap.put("Answer 3",ans3);
        hashMap.put("Answer 4",ans4);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Question1",question);
        bundle.putString("Answer 1",ans1);
        bundle.putString("Answer 2",ans2);
        bundle.putString("Answer 3",ans3);
        bundle.putString("Answer 4",ans4);

        String correctAnswer= CorrectAnswer;

        second mfragment=new second();
        mfragment.setArguments(bundle);

        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment1, mfragment).commit();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),question,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

and in second fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();// i am receiving error here. what should i do?
    String question = bundle.getString("Question1");


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);

    return root;


}
```

but receving error

```
2021-05-04 03:19:28.676 23166-23166/com.example.mcqapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mcqapp, PID: 23166
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mcqapp/com.example.mcqapp.activities.AdminPost}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in com.example.mcqapp:layout/activity_admin_post: Binary XML file line #25 in com.example.mcqapp:layout/activity_admin_post: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3703)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2216)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in com.example.mcqapp:layout/activity_admin_post: Binary XML file line #25 in com.example.mcqapp:layout/activity_admin_post: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25 in com.example.mcqapp:layout/activity_admin_post: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at fragments.second.onCreate(second.java:20)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2586)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:838)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1133)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1393)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3205)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:134)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:336)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.example.mcqapp.activities.AdminPost.onCreate(AdminPost.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3531)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3703)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
2021-05-04 03:19:28.677 23166-23166/com.example.mcqapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2216)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Comment: you have both of the fragment already loaded in Activity when activity is launched. so onCreate of both the fragment will be launched and the fragment where you expecting a  Argument `"Question1"` will fail because bundle will be null as no argument is sent to it. hence the nullpointerexception

Comment: Then how to solve it?

Comment: As mentioned in the error logs your layout name activity_admin_post has an error in line number 25 that's why it's causing crash. Check your layout file and fix the issue first .

Comment: if I comment out the bundle on the second fragment it code get started without error and then I reach back to square one. Problem is bundle is null. But it should not as i have not pressed button yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it . I removed the second fragment from the activity and converted the first fragment to frame layout as data was overlapping and added the first fragment programmatically

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</FrameLayout>

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment1,new first()).commit();
```

and the edited the second fragment on createView like this:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
if (bundle != null){

    String question = bundle.getString("Question1");
    String Question  = question.toString();
    textView.setText(Question);
```

I read so many StackOverflow questions and used frame layout as overlapping was occuring am i right?